# Linking multiple python functions together

Tags: python

Simple question on how to link (or string together) multiple functions that depend on each other. I have the following example function (in Jupyter):

```
### First function
def function_one():

    ## process one
    a = "one" + "two"
    print(a)

    ## process two
    b = "red" + "blue"
    print(b)

    ## process three
    c = "this" + "sucks"
    print(c)

    return a, b, c

### Second function
def function_two(a, b, c):

    ## process four
    d = a + b
    print(d)

    ## process five
    e = b + c
    print(e)

    ## process six
    f = a + c
    print(f)


    return d, e, f

### Third function
def function_three():

    g = a + b + c + d + e + f
    print(g)

    return g

### Calling functions
initial = function_one()
second = function_two(initial)
third = ... #I can't get past the following error to even link this function in
```

The first function works when called, but when I try to send that data downstream to the second function, I get this error:

```
onetwo
redblue
thissucks
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-7c5562b97c86> in <module>
      1 initial = function_one()
----> 2 second = function_two(initial)

TypeError: function_two() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'b' and 'c'
```

How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When returning multiple objects, you are actually returning a `tuple`. Ex:

```py
>>> def foo():
>>>     return 1, 2, 3

>>> type(foo())
<class 'tuple'>
```

So, right now the whole `tuple` is treated as argument `a` and hence `b` and `c` are missing. In order to pass that on as 3 **separate arguments**, you need to [*unpack*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) that tuple:

```py
initial = function_one()
second = function_two(*initial)
third = function_three(*initial, *second)
```

Comment: This is... magical. Many thanks. I like the other answer, too, but I think yours is the simplest way. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Assign the return values to variables then pass it to the second function:

```
a, b, c = function_one()
function_two(a, b, c)
```

For your third function you need it to accept parameters as well

```
def function_three(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    g = a + b + c + d + e + f
    print(g)
    return g
```

Then putting it all together:

```
a, b, c = function_one()
d, e, f = function_two(a, b, c)
g = function_three(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```